# Is it possible to pass struct list from c++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com-interop

I'm interested in calling a .NET piece of code from my C++ code.
The .NET code is into separated dll compiled with '*generate COM visible*', it consists of a method which accepts a list of 'item' struct.

Something like this:

```
struct item {
  int a;
  int b;
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public interface Ifoo {
    int GetFoo(ref IntPtr items,int nItems);
}

public class foo : Ifoo {
    int GetFoo(ref IntPtr items,int nItems) 
    {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < numMatches; ix++)
        {
            it = (item)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)((long)items + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(item))*ix)),typeof(item));
        }
    }
}
```

In c++ part, I have something similar to this..

```
std::vector<struct> foo;
foo.push_back(stru1); // stru1 is initialized anywhere...
foo.push_back(stru2); // and so on...

netInstance->GetFoo(reinterpret_cast<long*>(foo.data()),foo.size());
```

But this doesn't works.. all I get is a memory exception..

I also tried other approaches, such like SAFEARRAY but it seems that it doesn't work with custom structs..

Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing a lot of casting, that's where you triple check you're doing it correctly. You're probably not. You also need to drop your C++ code into your debugger and find out where and why it crashes.

Comment: C++/CLI lives in both worlds at the same time. That's my preferred way to interop.

Comment: It dies because the C++ code passes an IntPtr, not a ref IntPtr.  Getting rid of "ref" would be the quickest workaround, even though it is not the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, long may be 32 bits integers. You can try change `long*` to `long long*` in your C++ code, so that the size of the array matches the size of your data.

Comment: export signature is autogenerated, I can't modify.

Comment: I mean, you can change this line:
```netInstance->GetFoo(reinterpret_cast<long*>(foo.data()),foo.size());
```
to this
```netInstance->GetFoo(reinterpret_cast<long long*>(foo.data()),foo.size());
```
Do you have control over this part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you control both the C# part and the C++ part? Rather than marshal arrays, change the interface to work with individual items. The debugging will be easier.